# Swift: Candidate has non-matching type

Tags: swift

I try to use the following delegate in my implementation in swift (see below) which is failing with
"does not conform to protocol..." and error messages like "Candidate has non-matching type (PieChartView) -> Int"
Any Ideas?

```
@protocol PieChartViewDataSource <NSObject>

@required
- (int)numberOfSlicesInPieChartView:(PieChartView *)pieChartView;
- (double)pieChartView:(PieChartView *)pieChartView valueForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (UIColor *)pieChartView:(PieChartView *)pieChartView colorForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

failing Swift implementation

```
func numberOfSlicesInPieChartView(pieChartView: PieChartView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pieChartView(pieChartView: PieChartView, colorForSliceAtIndex index: Int) -> UIColor? {
    return UIColor(rgba: "#FF0000")
}

func pieChartView(pieChartView: PieChartView, valueForSliceAtIndex index: Int) -> Double {
    return 100/3;
}
```

Comment: Can you give the library you're using or the protocol source declaration of `PieChartViewDataSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func numberOfSlicesInPieChartView(pieChartView: PieChartView) -> CInt {
    return 32
}
func pieChartView(pieChartView: PieChartView, colorForSliceAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
}

func pieChartView(pieChartView: PieChartView, valueForSliceAtIndex index: UInt) -> Double {
    return 100/3;
}
```

Use `-> CInt` instead of `Int` because Swift `Int` could not be converted to C `int`. Same as `Double` -> `CDouble`

Use `index: UInt` instead of `index: Int`, because `NSUInteger` is *unsigned*.