# candidate has non-matching type with protocol

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit

I'm trying to create mock objects to test some GameKit-related code. After trying a couple routes, I settled on writing protocols for `GKTurnBasedMatch` & `GKTurnBasedParticipant`. Everything seems to work *except* when I try to reference one protocol in the other:

```
@objc protocol Participant {
    var player: GKPlayer! { get }
    var lastTurnDate: NSDate! { get }
    var status: GKTurnBasedParticipantStatus { get }
}

extension GKTurnBasedParticipant : Participant { }

@objc protocol Match {

    var matchID: String! { get }
    var creationDate: NSDate! { get }
    var participants: [AnyObject]! { get } // array of GKTurnBasedParticipant objects
    var status: GKTurnBasedMatchStatus { get }

    // *was* GKTurnBasedParticipant!
    var currentParticipant: Participant! { get }

    var matchData: NSData! { get }
    var message: String! { get }

    func loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)!)
    func endTurnWithNextParticipants(nextParticipants: [AnyObject]!, turnTimeout timeout: NSTimeInterval, matchData: NSData!, completionHandler: ((NSError!) -> Void)!)
    func saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData(matchData: NSData!, completionHandler: ((NSError!) -> Void)!)
}

extension GKTurnBasedMatch : Match { }
```

I need to be able to return mock participants, and it seems like I would be able to say that `currentParticipant` returns a `Participant` object instead of a `GKTurnBasedParticipant`, seeing as how the latter implements the protocol.

But it won't compile, claiming that:

```
.../GameKit+protocols.swift:51:1: error: type 'GKTurnBasedMatch' does not conform to protocol 'Match'
extension GKTurnBasedMatch : Match { }
^
.../GameKit+protocols.swift:28:6: note: protocol requires property 'currentParticipant' with type 'Participant'
        var currentParticipant: Participant! { get }
            ^
GameKit.GKTurnBasedMatch:8:13: note: candidate has non-matching type 'GKTurnBasedParticipant!'
  @objc var currentParticipant: GKTurnBasedParticipant! { get }
            ^
```

*Note: I've looked at the other [candidate has non-matching type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419930/swift-candidate-has-non-matching-type) question here & although it's the same error, it's unrelated to my question.*

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355689/swift-protocol-property-in-protocol-candidate-has-non-matching-type?rq=1. You need to to create a `typealias` for `Participant`.