# Swift protocol property in protocol - Candidate has non-matching type

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-protocols

I have a protocol (ProtocolA) containing a single property conforming to a second protocol (ProtocolB).

```
public protocol ProtocolA {        
    var prop: ProtocolB? { get }
}

public protocol ProtocolB {        
}
```

I'm trying to declare two classes that will implement those:

```
private class ClassA : ProtocolA {    
    var prop: ClassB?
}

private class ClassB : ProtocolB {
}
```

But I get an error:

> Type 'ClassA' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolA'
>
> Protocol requires property 'prop' with type 'ProtocolB?'
>
> Candidate has non-matching type 'ClassB?'

Which is annoying as ClassB conforms to ProtocolB.

in the good-old i'd probably just declare the property as:

```
@property (nonatomic) ClassB <ProtocolB> *prop;
```

but the only way it seems I can get around this in swift is by adding an ivar like:

```
private class ClassA : ProtocolA {        
    var _prop: ClassB?
    var prop: ProtocolB? { return _prop }
}
```

Is there no way around this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a `typealias` of the type that conforms to the other protocol. The way you did it is that `prop` has to be exactly of type `ProtocolB`, but you don't actually want that, you want a type that conforms to it instead.

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    typealias Prop : ProtocolB
    var prop: Prop? { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB {}


class ClassA : ProtocolA {
    var prop: ClassB?
}

class ClassB : ProtocolB {}
```

Comment: Well, now I get "ProtocolA can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" when I try to use it as:
`let array = Array<ProtocolA>`

What I forgot to say is that while the protocols are Public, the classes are Private (now edited) and I don't want to expose the internal classes.

Comment: How to do it if you can't modify `ProtocolA` ?