# Candidate has non-matching type of 'clearly matching type'

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, architecture, protocols

So here's the deal:

```
extension APIManager: LoginAPIManagerProtocol, LoginProtocol {}

protocol LoginAPIManagerProtocol { var user: User? { get } }

class APIManager {
...
var user: User?
...
}
```

All of these are in different files.
`LoginAPIManagerProtocol` is in a different module.
`APIManager` and the extension are in the same module.

Using Swift 5, ios 13 min SDK.

What I want is to expose the user variable(already defined and used in old legacy app) to new consumers(and tests to be mocked) via the defined protocol.

But!:

[all I get is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFXLW.png)

So.. what do I do now? Tried isolating the issue. Same error.

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355689/swift-protocol-property-in-protocol-candidate-has-non-matching-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer I got to:**

I'm not sure why I cannot expose the variable as it is. `User` isn't a protocol; it's just a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

And I tested exposing a simple `bool` from the class and it worked just fine.

But in the end exposing the whole `User` object isn't quite wise, because I might need to pull all its dependencies in the dependent module even though the module itself doesn't use all of them.

So I:

- declared a protocol (in the dependent module) used to expose what I need from `User`

```swift
public protocol ModuleUser {
  var id: Int64
}
```

- used that in the dependent protocol:

```swift
public protocol LoginAPIManagerProtocol {
...
var moduleUser: ModuleUser? { get }
...
}
```

- and the conformance:

```swift
extension APIManager: LoginAPIManagerProtocol, LoginProtocol {
    var moduleUser: ModuleUser? {
        return self.user
    }
}
```

And now I don't need to add the `User` object to the dependent module anymore;  which is noice :D